# Should we use Task.Delay to replace Thread.Sleep

Tags: multithreading, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

I am studying the new TPL to make my home made workflow work better.

Right now, I am entered into the maze of Task.Delay and Thread.Sleep. Acutally, Task.Delay(50).Wait() works just like Thread.Sleep(500). So which one should I use in my code?

from the many articles on internet, I have an impression that Task.Delay supports cancellation that Thread.Sleep does not support, so if I want to just block my thread for a duration without cancellation, will the use of Thread.Sleep be better than Task.Delay?

Comment: I do not want to assume a separate question, but I'm interested in - in this case, it's better to use a timer?

Comment: @BoguszM Task.Delay uses a Timer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you require cancellation, `Task.Delay` is an easy solution to that. I has overhead on top of `Thread.Sleep`: It constructs a timer and when you wait on this task you construct a wait handle that is signaled by the timer.

That said, you will only notice this overhead in tight loops (and sleep-throttled loops are rarely tight).

Use `Thread.Sleep` for blocking without cancellation. This is how it has always been done. It is well-known and idiomatic. Use `Task.Delay(...).Wait();` for cancellation support.

You can do this in many other ways. For example, construct a `SemaphoreSlim` or `TaskCompletionSource` and wait for it using a `CancellationToken`. That's not as simple as `Task.Delay`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Thread.Sleep`, which may call `Sleep()` API directly, will be better than `Task.Delay`, which create `Task` object. `Task.Deley` requires more overhead and a bit more long code.

*the easier code is, the better.*